# How to iterate over a DataSnapshot?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to iterate over the children of the contacts node. [image].

However my ListArray `contacts` only partially populates. The first two entries populate the array as expected (output from Logcat) but the 3rd entry fails to populate the array. Here is the `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView stringTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    stringTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getInstance();
    DatabaseReference dbRef= firebaseDatabase.getReference("County/Dublin");

    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            DataSnapshot contactSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("contacts");
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> contactChildren = contactSnapshot.getChildren();
            ArrayList<Contact> contacts= new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot contact : contactChildren) {
                Contact c = contact.getValue(Contact.class);
                Log.d("contact:: ", c.name + " " + c.number);
                contacts.add(c);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
}
```

And the model class `Contact.java`:

```
public class Contact {
public String name;
public String number;

public Contact() {
}


public Contact(String name, String number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}
}
```

Why is my `ListArray` not completely populating?

**UPDATE**

Here is what I've done with the suggested code example:

```
@Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<String> names= new ArrayList<>();
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                names.add(name);
                String number = ds.child("number").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", name);
            }
            for(int i=0; i < names.size(); i++){

                stringTextView.setText(stringTextView.getText() + names
                        .get(i) + " , ");
            }
        }
```

Array still not populating and no display to the screen.

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Firebase-Helper

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("County").child("Dublin").child("contacts");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList<String> names= new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            names.add(name);
            String number = ds.child("number").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name + " / " + number);
        }
        for(String name : names) {
            TextView stringTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.string_text_view);
            stringTextView.setText(stringTextView.getText().toString() + name + " , ");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
ger / 0213
paddy / 3345556
jeff / 55555
```

So, having this data, you can add it to an ArrayList, display it, do what you want with it.

Comment: thanks for the code example but still having problems populating the array.

Comment: What is the error? What's happening? What is the behaviour?

Comment: when I run the debugger, the output at the onDataChange method is

Comment: Is what? What does it say?

Comment: sorry.. the array is showing empty `names={ArrayList@19174} size=0`

Comment: Please see myp updated answer. You need to use: `stringTextView.getText().toString` in stead of `stringTextView.getText()`. Does it work now?

Comment: Hi Alex, still no joy.  `names={ArrayList@19174} size=0` and `stringTextView=null`. I presume the toString method is missing parenthesis which i inserted. I copied and pasted the code. i'm not too concerned with the TextView. Just want my names ArrayList to populate.

Comment: One thing I noticed is the node is County not Country. Shouldn't of copied and pasted! However now I have a null point exception (app crashes) for the second for loop. So names is still not populating.

Comment: I have added the parenthesis to `toString()` method, changed the child from `Country` to `County` and added the decration of the TextView inside the `onDataChange()` method. Now?

Comment: Same problem...here's the actual error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.gerhorgan.tableview.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:48)` So I presume the ListArray teams is still empty. Line 48 is `stringTextView.setText(stringTextView.getText().toString() + name + " , ");`

Comment: Are you sure your `TextView` does exist or your are finding it after the correct id?

Comment: thanks am mill. Never set the contentview in the onCreate method. Ended up back at square one with with only two names populating. But I exported the json file and noticed I had a space after the 3rd name child as can be seen above (between name and the colon). All working now..thanks

Comment: I spent 5 hours just to iterate over DataSnapshot. Omg google....

Answer (score 0):

Contact number 3 doesn't have quotes "" making it a number rather than a string. If you add quotes back it should fix the issue.