# Why my adapter inside the recyclerview did not display?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want to display a registration history in **parentsHomeActivity**, where all this data will be taken in the firebase database. I have created adapter coding and also **recent_registration_list_layout.xml** to display 2 attributes only:-

1. Student Name (fullName)
2. Tuition Name that has been registered (tuitionName).

There is no red error, crash or any logcat. The problem I encountered was, my adapter was not displayed in my apps. Really hope someone can teach me, new beginner in Android Studio. Thanks in advance.

**Database structure shows below, I only want to display the red circle attribute only:-**

[image]

**Adapter coding shows below:-**

```
public class RegistrationHistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RegistrationHistoryAdapter.ChildrenViewHolder>
{
    private Context mCtx;
    private List<StudentRegistration> childrenList;

public RegistrationHistoryAdapter(Context mCtx, List<StudentRegistration> childrenList)
{
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.childrenList = childrenList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ChildrenViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recent_registration_list_layout, parent, false);
    return new ChildrenViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChildrenViewHolder holder, final int position)
{
    final StudentRegistration studentRegistration = childrenList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    holder.tuitioNameView.setText(studentRegistration.getTuitioname());
    holder.studNameView.setText(studentRegistration.getFullname());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return childrenList.size();
}

class ChildrenViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView tuitioNameView, studNameView;
    CardView childrenLayout;

    public ChildrenViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        tuitioNameView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTuitionName);
        studNameView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFullName);
        childrenLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvChildren);
    }
}
}
```

**parentsHomeActivity coding shows below:-**

```
databaseReference.child("Student Registration").child(mAuth.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            //Iterating through all the values in database
            mChildrenList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                StudentRegistration studentRegistration = postSnapshot.getValue(StudentRegistration.class);
                mChildrenList.add(0, studentRegistration);
            }

            //Creating adapter
            mAdapters = new RegistrationHistoryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mChildrenList);

            //Adding adapter to recyclerview
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapters);
            mAdapters.notifyItemInserted(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }
    });

    //other method
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); //set fixed size for element in recycler view
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

**Recycleview layout in xml shows below:-**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvChildren"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton8"/>
```

Comment: Could you post XML code with RecyclerView that you are trying to set adapter to?

Comment: check whether you are receiving from firebase

Comment: @KacperKogut Already edit the question..

Comment: are you sure `DataSnapshot` contains any data?

Comment: @JinsLukose How to check? Can you help me?

Comment: @AliAhmed Yes sir. What do you think sir? Is that where is the issues came?

Comment: Debug your code to see if it is returning any response or not

Comment: mAdapters.notifyItemInserted(0); remove this.

Comment: Also check if you are getting data from firebase correctly.

Comment: @Adda  check mChildrenList Arraylist

Comment: @AliAhmed I dont know how to debug my code sir..

Comment: @ZarSaeed already remove it, still did not appear...

Comment: I believe you're doing wrong here `.child(mAuth.getUid())`.. Inside Student Registration the unique id doesn't looks like Auth Uid.  Can you show us. how you're storing responses on Firebase

Comment: @AliAhmed I already post the database structure sir...

Comment: @Adda use log like this to check
Log.e("data", String.valueOf(mChildrenList));

Comment: @Adda you need all students name and parent name or just 1 student record ?

Comment: @JinsLukose where should I put the log coding? Im so sorry, I really dont know how to debug hmmm

Comment: @AliAhmed If user A register 3 children, it will display all 3 children name and where the tuition they go..

Comment: @Adda just below mChildrenList.add(0, studentRegistration);

Comment: @JinsLukose okay nxt step? where should I see the logcat?

Comment: in LOGCAT under Error you will see data:  your array content

Comment: @JinsLukose empty sir, nothing shows...

Comment: so you are not getting data from firebase.Let me check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184615/discussion-between-adda-and-jins-lukose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store data this way

```
    String current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mDatabase.child("Student Registration").child(current_user).child(uid).setValue(studentRegistration).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
        {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Successfully registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, FinishActivity.class));
                finish();
            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Then for fetching data. use this code

```
    String current_user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();


    databaseReference.child("Student Registration").child(current_user).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            //Iterating through all the values in database
            mChildrenList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                StudentRegistration studentRegistration = postSnapshot.getValue(StudentRegistration.class);
                mChildrenList.add(studentRegistration);
            }

            //Creating adapter
            mAdapters = new RegistrationHistoryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mChildrenList);

            //Adding adapter to recyclerview
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapters);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
        {

        }
    });
```

In your Adapter change `onBindViewHolder` with this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChildrenViewHolder holder, final int position)
{
    holder.tuitioNameView.setText(childrenList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getTuitioname());
    holder.studNameView.setText(childrenList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getFullname());
}
```

Comment: But sir.. This part?             StudentRegistration studentRegistration = new StudentRegistration(uid, tuitioname, fullname, icnum, homeaddress, parentname, parentcontactnum, userUid, selectedTuitionPackage);

Comment: all other is same as yours. I just picked up the parts that you should change

Comment: My apps crash sir... Process: com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem, PID: 32093
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem.adapters.RegistrationHistoryAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RegistrationHistoryAdapter.java:41)
        at com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem.adapters.RegistrationHistoryAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RegistrationHistoryAdapter.java:17)

Comment: updating code. your `onBindViewHolder` is not correct

Comment: Sir.... my apps still crash, my coding mess already trying so many method hmmmm. Sir, are you free now? Can we connect just for a little awhile? So that you can see my latest coding hmm:(

Comment: i will be available after 3 hours

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184625/discussion-between-adda-and-ali-ahmed).

Answer (score 0):

Retrive firebase data with this method:

```
ref.child("Student Registeration").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
  ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     if(dataSnapshot.getValue != null) {
       for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            //get your object data from ds and add it to array list
        }
  //set adapter now
}
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
  // ...
}
});
```

Comment: BTW android studio warns to use  `holder.getAdapterPosition()` instead of `position`

Comment: @Adda so i think data is not receving

Comment: child of Student Registeration is with push id while you are using mAuth.getUid

Comment: that's the problem. You are using wrong mAuth.getUid.

Comment: @ZarSaeed okay sir.. Sir, can I have your email, so we can connect for awhile using chrome desktop...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935343/how-to-iterate-over-a-datasnapshot  
this thread will also help.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
From

```
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                StudentRegistration studentRegistration = postSnapshot.getValue(StudentRegistration.class);
                mChildrenList.add(0, studentRegistration);
            }
```

To

```
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                StudentRegistration studentRegistration = postSnapshot.getValue(StudentRegistration.class);
                mChildrenList.add(studentRegistration);
            }
```

And From

mAdapters.notifyItemInserted(0);

To

mAdapters.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Change From final StudentRegistration studentRegistration = childrenList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()); 

TO

final StudentRegistration studentRegistration = childrenList.get(position);


In adapter onbindView